# "Ties with industry" or "Ties with the industry"

Tags: articles, definite-article, countability

Is it correct to say:

> The school has strong ties with industry.

Should the definite article precede "industry"?

In order to make this question more clear: I think there's a couple of things at issue that I would like to ask about, beyond merely the specificity of industry. I understand that "industry" can be both a count noun and a non-count noun. So to say "ties with industry" means "industry" is used uncountably. But then when is it a count noun when noncount?

Also, if "industry" is preceded by the definite article to refer to a particular industry, does it mean it is countable? [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/industry) says so. All this being said, if a business school puts a line in a blurb, should it say:

> The school has strong ties with industry.

or

> The school has strong ties with the industry.

If that was a comment about a research university that has diverse academic disciplines, should it include the definite article?

Answer (score 1):

I find much of your question incomprehensible, but

**The school has strong ties to the industry** is not meaningful unless the preceding context makes clear what industry is being referenced. So this sentence cannot be said to be correct or incorrect if judged in isolation.

**The school has strong ties to industry** means that the school has strong ties to many industries.

Whether a sentence is **correct** does not depend solely on grammatical form; it often depends on context or intent or both in addition to grammatical form.

Comment: Part of my question is my research that shows when used with the definite article, "industry" is a count noun, without, noncount. Therefore I deem the question beyond _specificity_. I understand your point about context and intent, and I tried to include in my question context where the sentence would be used.

Comment: @Deansue - The question here is really the same for any noun, and whether you mean *industry* in general, or *the industry* that we are specifically talking about right now.